# Update data and its data type from another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to update t1 from t2 and change the data type at the same time.  However, I am getting this error message **"Incorrect syntax near '<'."**.

Please see below query. Please help

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[col1] = <t2.colA, nvarchar(6),>
    ,t1.[col2] = <t2.colB, tinyint,>
FROM t1 inner join t2 on t1.key = t2.key;
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  Your code is not syntactically correct.  It is rather unclear what you want to accompish.

Answer (score 1):

SQL will do implicit conversion.  But you can be explicit as well:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.[col1] = CAST(t2.colA AS nvarchar(6)),
        t1.[col2] = CAST(t2.colB AS tinyint)
    FROM t1 JOIN
         t2  
         ON t1.key = t2.key;
```